# In C++ (for Arduino) can you compile in the data for a graphic file?

Tags: c++, resources, arduino, embedded-resource

We have the need to embed several graphic files within our Arduino application.  What we're wondering is if it's possible to compile those files (or rather their data) directly into the resulting program so they won't have to be stored on something like an SD card and also, as being a fixed part of the program's memory, they would also save RAM for other things.

Our file types are standard 24-bit bitmaps if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool "bin2hex" and save the output into an `const char*` array in a header file or you roll up your own small program which reads in the bitmaps and generates a c++ header containing the data in hex format

Comment: This meets the goals part way, but will consume RAM.  To keep the data in flash, the code must also be modified to use program memory, see [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)